# rails routing, add path name also keep old urls working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

in my routes file, when i change

```
resources :foobar
```

to

```
resources :foobars, path: "foo-bars"
```

the urls become `example.com/foo-bars`, `example.com/foo-bars/1` etc.
this is ok.

but how can i also keep the old urls, `example.com/foobars`, `example.com/foobar/3` also working?

i know, i can hardcode it,

```
get "foobars", to: 'foobar#index'
get "foobar/:id", to: 'foobar#show'
...
```

but is there a clean way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define both of them

```
resources :foobars, path: "foo-bars"
resources :foobars, path: "foobars"
```

**EDIT:**

For custom actions instead of declaring them twice for each path like this,

```
resources :foobars, path: "foo-bars"
  collection do
    get 'bulk_new'
    patch 'bulk_create'
    get 'bulk_edit'
    patch 'bulk_update'
  end
end

resources :foobars, path: "foobars"
  collection do
    get 'bulk_new'
    patch 'bulk_create'
    get 'bulk_edit'
    patch 'bulk_update'
  end
end
```

Create common block and pass it to both resource method calls.

```
common_block  = lambda do
  collection do
    get 'bulk_new'
    patch 'bulk_create'
    get 'bulk_edit'
    patch 'bulk_update'
  end
end

resources :foobars, path: "foo-bars", &common_block
resources :foobars, path: "foobars", &common_block
```

Comment: I think he's looking for a one line elegant solution.

Comment: thanks, this seems better than mine. but let's wait a bit, if more elegant solution will be posted.

Comment: `%w(foo-bars foobars).each { |path| resources :foobars, path: path }` shorter, but uglier. I would stick to two lines